# How to keep array structure when saving record - activerecord/postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord

I created an array structure of hashes and i created a column in postgres to save that structure using the migration below

```
class AddKeyDirectionsToEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :calendar_events, :key_directions, :text, array:true, default: []
  end
end
```

now, the structure of the array is the one below

```
{
    :in => [
        [0] {
               :duration => "5 mins",
               :distance => "0.4 km",
            :travel_mode => "WALKING",
            :travel_type => nil
        },
        [1] {
               :duration => "12 mins",
               :distance => "5.3 km",
            :travel_mode => "TRANSIT",
            :travel_type => "SUBWAY"
        },
        [2] {
               :duration => "9 mins",
               :distance => "0.7 km",
            :travel_mode => "WALKING",
            :travel_type => nil
        }
    ]
}
{
    :out => [
        [0] {
               :duration => "10 mins",
               :distance => "0.7 km",
            :travel_mode => "WALKING",
            :travel_type => nil
        },
        [1] {
               :duration => "12 mins",
               :distance => "5.3 km",
            :travel_mode => "TRANSIT",
            :travel_type => "SUBWAY"
        },
        [2] {
               :duration => "6 mins",
               :distance => "0.4 km",
            :travel_mode => "WALKING",
            :travel_type => nil
        }
    ]
}
```

but for some reason in database it is saved like this

```
["{:in=>[{:duration=>\"5 mins\", :distance=>\"0.4 km\", :travel_mode=>\"WALKING\", :travel_type=>nil}, {:duration=>\"12 mins\", :distance=>\"5.3 km\", :travel_mode=>\"TRANSIT\", :travel_type=>\"SUBWAY\"}, {:duration=>\"9 mins\", :distance=>\"0.7 km\", :travel_mode=>\"WALKING\", :travel_type=>nil}]}", "{:out=>[{:duration=>\"10 mins\", :distance=>\"0.7 km\", :travel_mode=>\"WALKING\", :travel_type=>nil}, {:duration=>\"12 mins\", :distance=>\"5.3 km\", :travel_mode=>\"TRANSIT\", :travel_type=>\"SUBWAY\"}, {:duration=>\"6 mins\", :distance=>\"0.4 km\", :travel_mode=>\"WALKING\", :travel_type=>nil}]}"]
```

any ideas why? I tried chanign the type of array from :text, to :varchar and got same result. The only solution i found is using eval command to convert string back to array which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set column type to json.Use below migration command -

```
rails g migration AddKeyDirectionsToCalendarEvent key_directions:json
```

convert your structure to ruby array like this:

```
data = [{
    :in => [
        {
               :duration => "5 mins",
               :distance => "0.4 km",
            :travel_mode => "WALKING",
            :travel_type => nil
        },
        {
               :duration => "12 mins",
               :distance => "5.3 km",
            :travel_mode => "TRANSIT",
            :travel_type => "SUBWAY"
        },
        {
               :duration => "9 mins",
               :distance => "0.7 km",
            :travel_mode => "WALKING",
            :travel_type => nil
        }
    ]
},
{
    :out => [
        {
               :duration => "10 mins",
               :distance => "0.7 km",
            :travel_mode => "WALKING",
            :travel_type => nil
        },
        {
               :duration => "12 mins",
               :distance => "5.3 km",
            :travel_mode => "TRANSIT",
            :travel_type => "SUBWAY"
        },
        {
               :duration => "6 mins",
               :distance => "0.4 km",
            :travel_mode => "WALKING",
            :travel_type => nil
        }
    ]
}]
```

Then do,

```
event.key_directions=data
event.save
```

which will be saved in database like this,

```
[["updated_at", 2016-10-06 13:11:26 UTC], ["key_directions", "[{\"in\":[{\"duration\":\"5 mins\",\"distance\":\"0.4 km\",\"travel_mode\":\"WALKING\",\"travel_type\":null},{\"duration\":\"12 mins\",\"distance\":\"5.3 km\",\"travel_mode\":\"TRANSIT\",\"travel_type\":\"SUBWAY\"},{\"duration\":\"9 mins\",\"distance\":\"0.7 km\",\"travel_mode\":\"WALKING\",\"travel_type\":null}]},{\"out\":[{\"duration\":\"10 mins\",\"distance\":\"0.7 km\",\"travel_mode\":\"WALKING\",\"travel_type\":null},{\"duration\":\"12 mins\",\"distance\":\"5.3 km\",\"travel_mode\":\"TRANSIT\",\"travel_type\":\"SUBWAY\"},{\"duration\":\"6 mins\",\"distance\":\"0.4 km\",\"travel_mode\":\"WALKING\",\"travel_type\":null}]}]"], ["id", 4]]
```

You will get array when you will access it

```
    event.key_directions

 => [{"in"=>[{"duration"=>"5 mins", "distance"=>"0.4 km", "travel_mode"=>"WALKING", "travel_type"=>nil}, {"duration"=>"12 mins", "distance"=>"5.3 km", "travel_mode"=>"TRANSIT", "travel_type"=>"SUBWAY"}, {"duration"=>"9 mins", "distance"=>"0.7 km", "travel_mode"=>"WALKING", "travel_type"=>nil}]}, {"out"=>[{"duration"=>"10 mins", "distance"=>"0.7 km", "travel_mode"=>"WALKING", "travel_type"=>nil}, {"duration"=>"12 mins", "distance"=>"5.3 km", "travel_mode"=>"TRANSIT", "travel_type"=>"SUBWAY"}, {"duration"=>"6 mins", "distance"=>"0.4 km", "travel_mode"=>"WALKING", "travel_type"=>nil}]}]
```

Comment: just tried this and gave me this
`PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL: Expected ":", but found ",". CONTEXT: JSON data, line 1: ...:travel_mode=>\"WALKING\", :travel_type=>nil}]}",... : UPDATE "calendar_events" SET "key_directions" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "calendar_events"."id" = $3`

Comment: If you have already some records in database for this column you have to delete them first.

Comment: can you show a snippet from schema.rb which have create_table "events" do .. end

Comment: added just now, the column name is key_directions

Comment: i added also the SQL generated

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou Are you sure you did like this - **event.key_directions=data**. here data is ruby array. From your sql query it looks like data is a string.

Comment: yes something goes wrong, possibly a bug with something out of my control i feel. I am attaching an array to event.key_directions yes

Comment: added function for clarity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125116/discussion-between-dinesh-and-petros-kyriakou).

Comment: it worked, had to restart server for some reason. Thank you!